# Resize, rename and upload image with PHP

Tags: php

I would like to resize, rename and upload an image with PHP.

So my working script is the following:

```
$file_name = $_FILES['HOT_Logo']['name'];
$file_tmp_name = $_FILES['HOT_Logo']['tmp_name'];
$file_target = '../../images/hotel-logos/';
$file_size = $_FILES['HOT_Logo']['size'];

// Resize
$ratio = $width/$height;
if($ratio > 1) {
    $new_width = 300;
    $new_height = 300/$ratio;
}
else {
    $new_width = 300*$ratio;
    $new_height = 300;
}

$src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file_tmp_name));
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
imagedestroy($src);
imagepng($dst, $file_target.$file_name);
imagedestroy($dst);

// Rename file
$temp = explode('.', $_FILES['HOT_Logo']['name']);
$newfilename = 'new_img_name.'.end($temp);

// Upload image
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['HOT_Logo']['tmp_name'], $file_target.$newfilename)) {
    ...
}
```

Problem with this script is it upload two image:

- The renamed image but unresized.
- The non renamed image but resized.

Why ?

Comment: Your code is not in order :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a image, then moving the uploaded file, which is why it's creating two files. I believe your code is supposed to be:

```
$file_name = $_FILES['HOT_Logo']['name'];
$file_tmp_name = $_FILES['HOT_Logo']['tmp_name'];
$file_target = '../../images/hotel-logos/';
$file_size = $_FILES['HOT_Logo']['size'];

// Resize
$ratio = $width/$height;
if($ratio > 1) {
    $new_width = 300;
    $new_height = 300/$ratio;
}
else {
    $new_width = 300*$ratio;
    $new_height = 300;
}

// Rename file
$temp = explode('.', $file_name);
$newfilename = 'new_img_name.'.end($temp);

// Upload image
if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name , $file_target.$newfilename)) {
    $src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file_target.$newfilename));
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    imagedestroy($src);
    imagepng($dst, $file_target.$newfilename);
    imagedestroy($dst);

    ....
}
```

Comment: So you first upload the image and then reduce its dimensions ?

Comment: It's up to you. The important thing is to not create two files. You need to point to the same file to avoid the problem you have. In your code you are creating a file, then creating a new one from the uploaded file.

Comment: `imagepng($dst, $file_target.$file_name);` should become `imagepng($dst, $file_target.$newfilename);` to keep one file.